# Broken IPython notebook install Ubuntu 13.10 how to force reinstall

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I had Ipython notebook (even the dev version working great but then tried to install the "crosscat" component for the new BayesDB It Seems to have re-installed about everything on my system (and with some failures)

So now I can't run IPython Notebook anymore. I'm stuck, dead in the water.

I tried to go into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and remove all IPython directories. A pip reinstall from a local cloned repo of the dev version reports that all is up to date but there are still no IPython files in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages I also did a reinstall from Synaptic and still no IPython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.

When I try to start IPython notebook at the console I get the web page open with the message "Error connecting to server" with no files.

Which ipython reports /usr/local/bin/ipython which has a start-up file the console appears to have the server running (see below)

So what do I need to remove to get a reinstall to work? (Console output below)

```
tom@tom-sam:~$ ipython notebook --pylab inline
2013-12-08 08:41:36.389 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir:  u'/home/tom/.ipython/profile_default'
2013-12-08 08:41:36.557 [NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN:  http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
2013-12-08 08:41:36.645 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/tom
2013-12-08 08:41:36.645 [NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
2013-12-08 08:41:36.645 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
2013-12-08 08:41:36.645 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
Created new window in existing browser session.
2013-12-08 08:41:37.432 [tornado.access] 304 GET /tree (127.0.0.1) 44.66ms
2013-12-08 08:41:38.622 [tornado.access] 302 GET /notebooks?_=1386513698450 (127.0.0.1) 0.46ms
```

As a oh by the way when I looked at trying a apt remove of Ipython it also wanted to remove rabbitvcs-cli, rabbitvcs-nautilus3, vcs-gedit, Why Apt/synaptic would conflagurate them got me a bit nervous so I stopped before wrecking anything more...

Comment: Try to look in browser javascript console to see if you have more info. Do you have any kind of firewall ? "Error connecting to server" usually means websockets does not go through.

Comment: Saw this: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. Then refreshed page and my old notebook dir showed up but when I opened the last NB I had I got "Error loading notebook" and the terminal console showed 2013-12-08 10:23:22.593 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min.map (127.0.0.1) 0.40ms
When I reloaded the notebook page it loaded, and it seems to operate, so any idea how to fix? Seems to be missing some js?

Comment: Ahh I ran "python setup.py submodule" in the repo and all seems fine now,, thanks for the lead!

Comment: I had a similar problem - I could open the notebook listing, but not individual notebooks, with some weird Tornado errors. I uninstalled all the pip packages it depends on - `pip uninstall pyzmq jinja2 markupsafe tornado ipython` and then installed it once more `pip install ipython[notebook]`. I also started and stopped ipython couple of times and did full Chrome refreshes (`Ctrl + Shift + r`).

Comment: BTW, if you installed the development version, I guess you installed it via `pip` or `python setup.py install` - these methods install the package in your site-packages, not dist-packages (only Ubuntu's ipython package installs there). You can see what's your active version by issuing `pip uninstall pyzmq jinja2 markupsafe tornado ipython`. I wouldn't recommend manually removing any of these files either - use `pip uninstall` and/or `sudo apt-get purge`.

Comment: With dev you better have to `python setup.py develop`.

Comment: As mentioned above "python setup.py submodule" seems to have fixed all.. seems that got the required JS package..